# blackberry replacing treeview node image with my own

Tags: blackberry, treeview

i want to replace the node image with my own custom image is it possible? I have found way to add icons to treeview but that is just adding images to treeview not replacing the node image please share your experiance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look & feel of standard BlackBerry GUI elements is controlled by current [theme](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/themes/). If you need to have different look and feel of a standard TreeField instance then you need to create [your own custom field](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_custom_field_508117_11.jsp).